# Comparing multiple gls' objects using anova.gls

Tags: r, anova, generalized-least-squares

I got a warning message when I was trying to do anova for two nlme::gls objects. Here is an example:

```
require(nlme)
set.seed(123)
y<-rnorm(100,10,2)
x1<-rnorm(100)
x2<-sample(1:5,100,T)
x3<-rt(100,20)
x4<-rbinom(100,1,0.3)
fit1<-gls(y~x1+x2+x3+x4,correlation=corAR1(form=~1|x4))
fit2<-gls(y~x3+x4,correlation=corAR1(form=~1|x4))
anova(fit1,fit2)
     Model df      AIC      BIC    logLik   Test  L.Ratio p-value
fit1     1  7 421.5587 439.4359 -203.7794                        
fit2     2  5 413.9855 426.8590 -201.9928 1 vs 2 3.573242  0.1675
Warning message:
In nlme::anova.lme(object = fit1, fit2) :
  fitted objects with different fixed effects. REML comparisons are not meaningful.
```

Dose anybody know what the message means? Should I do the following rather than above?

```
> anova(fit1, L=c(-1, -1, 1, 1))
Denom. DF: 95 
 F-test for linear combination(s)
(Intercept)          x1          x2          x3 
         -1          -1           1           1 
  numDF  F-value p-value
1     1 281.9844  <.0001
```

Why the numDF is one here? It seems 2?

Answer (score 7):

The two GLS models are fitted by maximising a restricted (or residual) maximum likelihood function, the REML in the warning. This approach gives better estimates of the variance components of the model; the `correlation=corAR1(form=~1|x4)` part. However, REML estimates are not appropriate for comparing models where the fixed effects parts differ. The fixed effects parts of your two models are

```
x1+x2+x3+x4
```

and

```
x3+x4
```

You should re-estimate the two models using maximum likelihood, and then refit the chosen model using the default REML to get the best estimate for the covariance matrix of the model. This is quite easily done, for example:

```
anova(update(fit1, . ~ ., method = "ML"),
      update(fit2, . ~ ., method = "ML"))
```

The `update()` calls will refit the models in-place and throw away the objects once `anova()` is done with them. The `. ~ .` part just indicates that no changes should be made to the model response or fixed effects. I forget if this is even need. If you want the ML models for later, do

```
fit1ml <- update(fit1, . ~ ., method = "ML")
fit2ml <- update(fit2, . ~ ., method = "ML")
anova(fit1ml, fit2ml)
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice reply!I am also wondering What's the difference between your anova(fit1ml, fit2ml) and my anova(fit1, L=c(-1, -1, 1, 1))?

Answer (score 0):

The L= c(-1, -1, 1, 1) specifies the contrast you would like to test; as a result, you are testing for $\beta_0 + \beta_1= \beta_2 + \beta_3$ by specifying the command.

You can test $\beta_1= 0$ and $\beta_2= 0$ using *F*-tests by issuing the following command:

```
L<- matrix(0, nrow= 2, ncol= 5, dimnames= list(NULL, names(coef(fit1))))
L[1, "x1"]<- 1
L[2, "x2"]<- 1
L
anova(fit1, L= L)
```

You will obtain a similar result as in

```
anova(fit1, fit2)
```

Hope it helps.