# Hierarchical regression of a linear mixed model

Tags: regression, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

I am trying to determine which would be the best model type to run on my data. After reading through this [chapter's introduction](https://www.sagepub.com/sites/default/files/upm-binaries/47528_ch_1.pdf), it seems I would be best suited to run a hierarchical regression on a multivariate linear mixed model. However, this seems like it could be difficult to interpret and am not sure that it is a common practice.

Concerning my data, I have multiple DVs (I could also run a normal linear mixed model for each variable), and I would use a step-wise hierarchical regression with my demographics and defining IVs to determine what is most predictive. All data is participant-wise and is not a repeated-measures design. However, the participants are grouped on a second and third level. I was considering the second level as a random effect and the third level as a random (variance) and fixed effect (variable).

These are the models that I am considering (only a linear mixed model, not multivariate):

```
  model1a <- lme(dv ~ iv1, random = list(~1|secondlevel, ~1|thirdlevel), data = mydata)
  model1b <- lme(dv ~ iv1 + iv2, random = list(~1|secondlevel, ~1|thirdlevel), data = 
  mydata)
  model1c <- lme(dv ~ iv1 + iv2 + iv3_thirdlevelvariable, random = list(~1|secondlevel, 
  ~1|thirdlevel), data = mydata)
```

Could anyone provide guidance as to whether this would be an appropriate analysis based on statistical practices? I have just not seen that hierarchical regression was common in linear mixed-effects models.

Many thanks!

EDIT:

I have various demographic and cultural variables (IVs; let's say around 8). I have multiple categorical questions (DVs; let's say around 20). The DVs are not all regarding the same topic in the study, rather split over three topics. So, I am looking at them separately for each question (as they are categorical). I have a large dataset in which each line is a new participant (no repeated measures; ie. first 'grouping' level). I grouped the participants into 50 groups, based on location (ie. second grouping level). Given that 50 groups is too many, I grouped the second-level groups into 3 broad groups based on general location (ie. third grouping level).

I am planning to run the analysis on each DV and add in the demographics/cultural IVs in a hierarchical-fashion. I was thinking to treat the second- and third-grouping levels (specific location and broad location) as random effects. I also had IVs that were computed based on the third level groups (ie. a culture variable between broad location groups), which I would include in the regression.

My question is whether such a practice is commonly used/statistically reasonable.
I hope this clarification is useful.

Comment: Please explain your study design in detail

Comment: @RobertLong I have updated the post (hopefully) with a clarification of the data and my statistical question. Many thanks for having a look.

Comment: Can I also ask whether the response from Gavin Simpson on this post (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82391/comparing-multiple-gls-objects-using-anova-gls) would be appropriate to compare lme() models of a hierarchical regression?

Comment: I'm not sure because I don't understand your study design